# Is there an easy way to use the jquery-infinite-pages gem with search conditions for infinite scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, infinite-scroll

I am using the [jquery-infinite-pages](https://github.com/magoosh/jquery-infinite-pages) gem along with the kaminari gem for infinite scrolling for my index action. I got it working, but I would also like to have a search feature that sorts by name, etc. I got that working also, but the code is really messy and really 'hacky' as I have to use jquery to target the href and append the search terms at the end of the url.

**index.js.erb**

```
$("<%=j render(partial: 'drawings', object: @drawings) %>")
  .appendTo($(".gallery-page"));

<% if @drawings.last_page? %>
  $('.pagination').html("That's all, folks!");
<% else %>
  $('.pagination')
  .html("<%=j link_to_next_page(@drawings, 'Next Page', :remote => true) %>");
  <% if @search.present? %>
    var hrefEl = $('.pagination a').attr('href');
    $('.pagination a').attr('href', hrefEl + "&search=" + "<%= @search %>");
  <% end %>
  <% if @order.present? %>
    var hrefEl = $('.pagination a').attr('href');
    $('.pagination a').attr('href', hrefEl + "&order=" + "<%= @order %>");
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the jquery to append to the end of the href.

**index.html.haml**

```
%div
  = form_tag("/drawings", method: 'get', id: 'search-form') do
    = select_tag :search, options_for_select(name_list, params[:search]), prompt: "Search for..."
    = select_tag :order, options_for_select(order_list, params[:order]), prompt: "Order by..."
    = submit_tag "Search", id: 'search-button', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'

.gallery
  .gallery-page
    = render 'drawings', object: @drawings

.pagination
  = link_to_next_page(@drawings, 'Next Page', remote: true)

= render partial: 'pagination_search.js', object: @search unless @search.nil?
= render partial: 'pagination_order.js', object: @order unless @order.nil?
```

I had to create 2 partials that uses jquery to append to the end of the href.

**drawings_controller.rb**

```
def index
  if params[:search].blank? && params[:order].blank?
    @drawings = Drawing.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
  else
    if params[:search].blank?
      @search = "%"
    else
      @search = params[:search].gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "")
    end
    if params[:order] == "Newest" || params[:order].blank?
      @order = "DESC"
    else
      @order = "ASC"
    end
    @drawings = Drawing.joins(:picture).where("name LIKE ?", @search).order("created_at #{@order}").page(params[:page])
  end
  @search = nil if @search == "%"
  @order = params[:order]
end
```

And my index action is a mess with alot of conditional statements.

**_drawings.html.haml**

```
- @drawings.each do |drawing|
  = link_to drawing_path(drawing) do
    %img{src: drawing.image.thumb.url, class: 'gallery-image'}
```

So my question is, is there a more cleaner and elegant way of using the jquery-infite-pages gem for infinite scrolling along with search parameters? Or does this gem not support something like this? Is there another gem that does this?

Comment: Can you show us your controller and the generated HTML of the next page link when you're searching and ordering? These should be set by kaminari

Comment: @PabloGonzálezAlba added the index action. The generated HTML of the next page link is the same as what `index.html.haml` uses when searching and ordering.